# Insertar elemento en un arreglo python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo en un arreglo los siguientes numeros: 1 2 7 4 6 7 8
Como hago para insertar el siguiente numero de cada numero par luego de este?
o sea que me quede lo siguiente: 12**3**74**5**6**7**78**9**.

```
    def par(a):
        n2=[]
        for i in range(len(n)):
           if a[i] % 2 != 0:
               n2.append(a[i])
           else:
               n2.insert(a[i]+1)
```

Comment: Define un poco más, añade formato, muestra lo que has hecho. Son cosas muy necesarias en una pregunta

Comment: Es una pregunta ambigua. 1234678 es un número y es par. Numero y dígito no necesariamente es lo mismo. Explica mejor el contexto, cuál es la salida deseada y el código que has intentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene algunos errores (aparte de que la variable `n` no está definida dentro de la función, supongo que te referías a la variable `a`).

- La función no retorna nada. Deberías retornar la lista `n2` que estás construyendo
- `insert()` requiere dos parámetros, y solo le pasas uno. Hay que pasarle también en qué lugar de la lista lo quieres meter. Pero en realidad no lo necesitas, pues metes al final, por lo que vale usar `append()`
- En tu bucle, si es impar metes el número original y si es par metes el siguiente entero, por lo que en realidad no estás metiendo los pares.

Por tanto las correcciones son:

- Mete todos los números a la lista n2 usando append, tanto si son pares como si no, y después **sólo si es par**, mete el siguiente entero
- Retorna la lista resultante

Además puedes mejorar el bucle for iterando por los valores en vez de hacerlo por los índices, es más "pythónico":

```py
def par(datos):
    resultado=[]
    for n in datos:
        resultado.append(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            resultado.append(n+1)
    return resultado
```

Si la función en vez de una lista recibe una cadena, como "1274678", el bucle sirve el mismo, pero debes convertir cada dígito a entero antes de mirar si es par o impar. La lista que construyes como resultado puedes convertirla de nuevo en cadena, convirtiendo a cadena cada elemento y concatenando todos mediante `"".join()`. Quedaría entonces así:

```
def par(datos):
    resultado=[]
    for digito in datos:
        n = int(digito)
        resultado.append(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            resultado.append(n+1)
    return "".join(str(x) for x in resultado)
```

Y ahora podrías usarlo de este modo:

```
result = par("1274678")
```

para obtener como resultado la cadena "12374567789"

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion. Me ayudo bastante

Answer (score 1):

Si es un arreglo con los números, solo basta con recorrer el arreglo y:
1- El elemento actual es insertado, si o si, en el arreglo resultante: `n2.append(elem)`
2- Si el elemento actual es par (`elem % 2 == 0`), entonces insertar: `n2.append(elem+1)`. No es necesario un `else`.

```py
def par(a):
    n2 = []
    for elem in a:
        n2.append(elem)
        if elem % 2 == 0:
            n2.append(elem+1)
    return n2
```

Prueba:

```
print(par([1, 2, 7, 4, 6, 7, 8]))
# Imprime: [1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9]
```